# F# calling function that returns record in for loop only executes once

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I mainly work in C# and am new to F#/function languages and I'm having a problem with a pretty simple program.
I have a function that creates a record with two integer fields. The fields are chosen `System.Random.NextDouble` inside a `match` to align with certain probabilities. I then have a for loop that should run the `createCustomer` function four times.

The problem I'm having is that the `Customer` is the same for all 10 iterations of the for loop and the `printfn` inside of `getIATime` only seems to execute once.

Program.fs

```
open Simulation

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    printfn "Test"

    for i in 1 .. 10 do
        let mutable customer = createCustomer
        printfn "i: %d\tIA: %d\tService: %d" i customer.interArrivalTime customer.serviceTime


    ignore (System.Console.ReadLine()) //Wait for keypress @ the end
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Simulation.fs

```
module Simulation

type Customer = {
    interArrivalTime: int
    serviceTime: int
}

let createCustomer =
    let getRand =
        let random = new System.Random()
        fun () -> random.NextDouble()

    let getIATime rand =
        printf "Random was: %f\n" rand 
        match rand with
        | rand when rand <= 0.09 -> 0
        | rand when rand <= 0.26 -> 1
        | rand when rand <= 0.53 -> 2
        | rand when rand <= 0.73 -> 3
        | rand when rand <= 0.88 -> 4
        | rand when rand <= 1.0 -> 5

    let getServiceTime rand =
        match rand with
        | rand when rand <= 0.2 -> 1
        | rand when rand <= 0.6 -> 2
        | rand when rand <= 0.88 -> 3
        | rand when rand <= 1.0 -> 4

    {interArrivalTime = getIATime (getRand()); serviceTime = getServiceTime (getRand())}
```

Comment: You don't need that "mutable" keyword inside the loop. It's the same as with C# in this case. If you were to declare a variable inside a loop in C#, it wouldn't be the same variable but rather a new variable for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Good call, forgot I even had that in there. I had tried adding it to see if it would've fixed the issue I was having

Comment: If you're going to do code review, there's also abuse of `match`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `getCustomer` is not a function, but a *value*. Its body is executed only once during program initialization, and the result is stored in a field, which can then be accessed. When you think that you "call" the function, you actually merely reference the value. No calling is going on, because there is nothing to call.

To make `getCustomer` a function, give it a parameter. This is how functions differ from values in F#: if you have a parameter, you're a function; if not - you're a value. Since there is no actual data that you'd want to pass to the function, you can give it a "dummy" ("placeholder") parameter of type `unit`. This type has exactly one value, and that value is written as `()`:

```
let createCustomer () =
    let getRand =
        let random = new System.Random()
        fun () -> random.NextDouble()

    ...
```

Then call it like this:

```
for i in 1 .. 10 do
    let mutable customer = createCustomer()
    printfn "i: %d\tIA: %d\tService: %d" i customer.interArrivalTime customer.serviceTime
```

Comment: That was my problem. I ended up putting `fun () -> {...}` at the end instead to stop the `System.Random()` from being created each loop. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that functions can be declared without explicit parameters, but you still need to supply at least one parameter when you call. I think technically they are values that contain functions. This is rather common in F#, and can be a source of confusion for a beginner.